# lsi sas 3442E-R Low write speed (4 MB/s) IN RAID 1 MOD

Tags: sas, raid1

R controller (B1 Revision) Latest BIOS and MPT version

MotherBoard: ASUS P8H77-M LE, Latest BIOS version

sas 3442E-R insert into PCI-E x4 slot. in x16 slot - not detect motherboard

DISKS:

- WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 3 Gbit/s Speed
- WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 6 Gbit/s Speed (detect how 1.5 Gbit/s)
- Hitachi sata 250Gb with 3 Gbit/s Speed  -- FOR TEST

All disk connect to sas3442E-R over sff8484->4xSATA cable

IN NON-RAID MODE:

- WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 3 Gbit/s Speed: Read: 109 MB/s WRITE: 106 MB/s
- WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 6 Gbit/s Speed Read: 133 MB/s WRITE: 126 MB/s
- Hitachi sata 250Gb with 3 Gbit/s Speed  Read: 65 MB/s WRITE: 64 MB/s

IN RAID 0 MODE:

- (WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 3 Gbit/s) + (WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 6 Gbit/s)
  Read: 216MB/s  WRITE: 198 MB/s

IN RAID 1 MODE:

- (WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 3 Gbit/s) + (WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 6 Gbit/s)
  Read: 167 MB/s  **WRITE: 4 MB/s**

IN RAID 1 MODE:

- (WD sata 1TB BLACK, with 3 Gbit/s) + (TEST Hitachi sata 250Gb with 3 Gbit/s)
  Read: 70 MB/s  **WRITE: 3.8 MB/s**

This is not the performance I was expecting, what could be the problem?

Comment: Wait for the RAID array to sync itself before testing would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have no disk write Cache enabeld.